# Ubuntu (wubi version) cannot connect to the internet network

Tags: networking, network-manager

I am new in the world of ubuntu. Recently I installed the wubi version of ubuntu in my desktop and I have the following problem: It cannot be connected to the wired network. When I use the PC in windows-7 mode everything is ok.

Ubuntu version: **Ubuntu 12.04.4 LTS**

Any idea of what can cause this problem?

Some extra info about ethernet card:
**02:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 06)**

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please edit your question to add details of your ethernet card from the terminal: lspci -nn | grep 0200 and your Ubuntu version: lsb_release -d

Answer (score 0):

When I started Ubuntu I had the same problem. My solution was ensuring that networking was enabled. To do this: click on the wifi/arrows that signify the internet connect and near the bottom you can check/uncheck "Enable Networking". That may seem somewhat trivial, but that is what happened to me and several others.

Comment: Thanks for your help but I had already done it and nothing. Could it be a problem of network manager?

Comment: @user247404 Quite possibly. I don't have much experience with Ubuntu myself, hopefully someone more experienced can help you.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem might be drivers.
If your computer came with Windows, the drivers were probably installed there. But they might not be in Ubuntu.

Try installing the drivers for your network card, this should be the drivers you need:
http://www.realtek.com/downloads/downloadsView.aspx?Langid=1&PNid=13&PFid=5&Level=5&Conn=4&DownTypeID=3&GetDown=false#2

Remember to grab the drivers for linux, not Windows ;)

Good Luck.

Comment: I cheked it and the drivers are there

Comment: Very strange, when I used another connection line, connection was established normally. It is strange because with the previous connection line internet used to work when the desktop was in windows mode. In addition When I used the laptop the internet connection used to work either in windows or linux. However it did not work only when I used the desktop in linux mode.